# Decomposing $\frac{x^2}{x+y}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x+y}$. I am interested in decomposing how much of a change in $f(x,y)$ is due to $x$ and how much how much of it is due to $y$. I could use a linear approximation based on partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, but I'm wondering if an exact decomposition exists. The Quadratic Approximation Lemma provides an exact decomposition for quadratic functions, and I'm wondering if there is an exact decomposition for a non-linear function like this one.